# Почему не удаляются посты с картинками в блоге?

Tags: yii2, framework

Yii2 недавно начал изучать и вот уже пару дней не могу разобраться с этим. При попытке удаления поста в админ.панели браузер как бы зависает. Удаляется только если это сделать в базе. Картинки загружаются, но потом имеют такой вид и тоже не удаляются. Если нужен код-могу выложить здесь [image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Что-то с маршрутизацией. Адреса контроллеров правильно прописаны?

Comment: вы имеете ввиду namespase? "/blog/delete-image" никуда не ведет. может зависит от настроек урл менеджера, или по дефолту  в BlogContoller и actionDeleteImage? код BlogController здесь выложу а UrlManager по ссылке https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/TTDNHWUHWS

Comment: По прямым ссылкам картинки открываются?

Comment: если открывать пост в админке http://admin.site.com/blog/blog/view?id=2#1 - то их видно, прокрутка fotorama есть, на frontede ничего нет. из запросов видно, что  в(blog/blog/index) запрос идет, а не в blog/image-delete как ожидается. но что там менять в url-manager - непонятно.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы картинки удалились, нужно  в form.php указать ещё один модуль     `blog/blog/image-delete`